# How to mock [] functions with Rspec?

Tags: rspec

Using Rspec, I can mock `Dir.glob("/my/dir/*.tmp")` doing this:

```
expect(Dir).to receive(:glob).with("/my/dir/*.tmp")
```

How would I mock `Dir["/my/dir/*.tmp"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
expect(Dir).to receive(:"[]").with("/my/dir/*.tmp")
```